# Analog of setting trap flag in Event Flags in Thread Context for ARM64

Tags: c++, cpu-registers, vscode-debugger, arm64

I have a project which I am migrating to **ARM64** and in the **x86** project I am doing this:

```
CONTEXT ctx;
ctx.EFlags |= 0x100;
```

This is basically setting the trap flag in the event flag of the the thread context allowing the debugger to run in single step mode(basically put breakpoints and move one instruction at a time). But EFlags are not available in the CONTEXT structure in ARM64 architecture and I can't find what is the analog for this in ARM64. I want a more robust resource on registers in general and the ARM64 analog for event flags. Resources of answers would really be appreciated. [This](https://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/%7Eamza/www.mindsec.com/files/x86regs.html) is where I read about the event flags, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) about trap flag. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with Windows and not able to test this, but *probably* like this:

```
ARM64_NT_CONTEXT ctx;
ctx.Cpsr |= 0x200000;
```

If you were implementing this yourself in kernel mode, you'd write to bit 21 of `spsr_el1`. Quoting [the manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest) (p. C5-460 in version G.b):

```
SS, bit [21]

    Software Step. Set to the value of PSTATE.SS on taking an exception to EL1,
    and conditionally copied to PSTATE.SS on executing an exception return
    operation in EL1
```

Now, the naming around `spsr`, `cpsr` and `pstate` is somewhat messed up. In A32/T32, ARM called the current program state `cpsr` and had a system register by that name which you could modify. In A64, they call it `pstate` but do not give you a register to modify directly (they give you a bunch of registers for parts of it, like `pan` and `nzcv`). On exception entry, that state is copied to `spsr_elX`, and on exception return the value from that register is copied back into the processor state.
Thus, `spsr`, `cpsr` and `pstate` all refer to the same thing in the context of a saved thread state.

And the `ARM64_NT_CONTEXT` struct contains a register called `Cpsr`, implying that you can set `spsr_el1` that way.

Note: Unless the API you're dealing with is a kernel API, it's likely that Windows filters out certain bits from that field, most notably the lowest few bits, which encode the exception level that the thread/process runs at. Whether or not they filter out the single-step bit I cannot say, but if they don't do so on x64, I would hope that they don't do on arm64 either.